# python to make an iterative map

Tags: python

I am trying to make an iterative map and plot it. I am just starting to learn python.
Here is my code: I feel  I am making an amature mistake in syntax, my code only gives my a straight line.

```
N = 10000
aa = linspace(2, 4, N)
xx = zeros(N)
for jj in range(N):a = aa[jj]
x0 = rand()
for ii in range(1, 100): x0 = a *x0 *(1 -x0)
xx[jj] = x0
plot(aa, xx, '.')
```

What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Please explain yourself further, and format that code you posted :)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn fixed the immediate display problem - it's now up to the OP to indent properly :)

Comment: I'm guessing your code also does something like `from numpy import *` and `from matplotlib.pyplot import *`: you need to include those import statements to make it easy for others to run your code.

Comment: @Marius i think `rand()` is meant to be random.random() too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python the indenting is more important than in other languages.

Just by rearranging your code (and putting in namespaces and such, so it's obvious where functions are coming from), i get this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
import random



N = 10000
aa = numpy.linspace(2, 4, N)
xx = numpy.zeros(N)
for jj in range(N):
    a = aa[jj]
    x0 = random.random()
    for ii in range(1, 100):
        xx[jj] = a *x0 *(1 -x0)

pyplot.plot(aa, xx, '.')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: thank you all, I am sorry about my inexpert formatting for questions.

Comment: Yes, I did not understand about the importance of indenting! That made all the difference!

Comment: @user2081556 that's okay.  Please mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

N = 10000
aa = np.linspace(2, 4, N)
xx = np.zeros(N)
for jj in range(N):
    a = aa[jj]
    x0 = random.random()
    for ii in range(1, 100):
        x0 = a *x0 *(1 -x0)
    xx[jj] = x0
plt.plot(aa,xx,'.')
plt.show()
```

This generates the attached [image: plot]